# Is it possible to use CUDA 2.0 from latest OS?

Tags: ubuntu, cuda

CUDA 2.0 was released at 2008 and the official supporting os is very old.
From latest OS such as Ubuntu 22.04 or WIN10, is it possible to use the CUDA 2.0?
The GPU is RTX-4080.

From several web serching, strictly saying it seems CUDA is not backward compatible.
So I'm afraid some function of CUDA 2.0 is not avaialble from latest CUDA toolkit.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "use"? Compile code, run existing binaries, install the toolkit?

Comment: Well yes, major version releases are allowed to break APIs (according to [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/)). While it might be possible to somehow use it on a recent OS in theory, I think you might have an easier time replacing those old API's while possibly asking here, what the modern version of some APIs is. 15 years is a lot of time for software.

Answer (score 1):

> saying it seems CUDA is not backward compatible. So I'm afraid some function of CUDA 2.0 is not avaialble from latest CUDA toolkit.

Most CUDA functionality remains available with increasing versions. The API might *change* somewhat - different function name, different parameters etc. - but few things disappear.

As for the exceptions - you basically need to check the release notes from the [different versions](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive): Each version says what's been deprecated or removed, if anything. For example: v11.8.0 [declares 32-bit compilation to be deprecated](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.8.0/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html). As @paleonix notes, however - for versions before 8.0 there's no archived on-line documentation.

So, instead of trying to get CUDA 2.0 to work, check whether your functionality is available with more recent versions. (And it probably is.)

Comment: Although it is not quite that easy for versions lower than 8.0. They don't have archived online documentation and at least for e.g. 3.2 all links to both documentation and Toolkit downloads are dead. Which is another point against trying to get 2.0 to run.

Comment: @paleonix: But they do have documentation as part of the download, IIANM.

Comment: I haven't tried all download links, but the ones I tried were dead.

Comment: @paleonix: :-O ... so, they shouldn't be. Can you file a bug about this?

Comment: I just did: Bug ID 4166156